# No confirmation after pressing power button on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, shutdown

I have a strange problem; Mac sleeps immediately after I press the power button, instead of showing a confirmation box to ask what I want to do. So, whenever I miss-pressed the power button when trying to reach delete button, it sleeps, and I have to turn it on again.

I'm trying to find back the confirmation box and I've googled for hours, but still get no luck in finding a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it's a feature of OSX 10.9

- http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1602151
- http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/289040-os-x-109-dps-builds/page-24

Comment: Link only answers are not very helpful.  The links can "go away" in future.  Can you add relevant point from your links to improve the answer?

Comment: Furthermore, how do you figure the OP runs OS X 10.9, which isn't even released yet?

Comment: @slhck He's right on this, I'm using 10.9 DP7. No idea how he figured it out, but this helps.

Answer (score 3):

With the recent release of OSX 10.9, Apple has changed the power button to make your computer automatically sleep on a quick press of the button, if the button is accidentally pressed, you will have to wait a second, and either press the power button again, or the space bar to wake your computer (slower systems may take longer to sleep, and awake). If you would like to access the power dialog box, you can either: hold the control key and press the power button, hold the control key and press the eject button (if present on your keyboard), or hold the power button for 1.5 seconds. At this time there is no way to adjust these settings.

My personal opinion is that this is a downgrade in functionality, but will not be changed by apple in the near future, if you consistently press your power button by accident your options are to down-grade to OSX 10.8, train yourself to not press the button accidentally, or wait/search for a third party plugin to modify this behavior.

see: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5869?viewlocale=en_US

Answer (score 0):

On new OSX 10.9, just click **CTRL+[Shutdown Button]** and it does the same as before :-)